# highchart 3d stacklabel column position

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I add

```
stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
        fontSize: '12px',
        color: '#333333',
        align: 'center',
    },
},
```

inside yAxis: the label displays at random places, not always in the center. This only happens when using highchart-3d, Need helps to make labels in a fixed position relates to the columns. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/yaht5eqm/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question and add a small picture which displays the issue? It may help other readers to provide you a solution.

Comment: Thanks, edited already.

Comment: This issue should be already solved on Highcharts developer branch: http://jsfiddle.net/yaht5eqm/1/

Comment: Thanks, the problem is fixed after using developer branch.